# Pyinstaller package not found even after a explicit hidden import (gino-starlette)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, starlette, gino

I've been trying to package an application which requires `gino-starlette`. I've tried including the requirement as a hidden import with command
`pyinstaller --hidden-import gino_starlette --hidden-import gino.ext --noconfirm windows_runner.py --clean`
but to no avail, the logs read that the gino_starlette was found, but running the executable gives the same error.
Log while running the executable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gino\ext\__init__.py", line 72, in find_spec
ImportError: Cannot import gino.ext.starlette - is gino-starlette a valid extension and installed?
```

Piece of code which throws the specific error (this resides in gino.ext, which loads all extensions needed by gino):

```
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        target = self._redirects.get(fullname)
        if target:
            mod = sys.modules.get(target)
            if mod is None:
                spec = find_spec(target)
                spec.loader = _GinoExtensionCompatProxyLoader(fullname, spec.loader)
                return spec
            else:
                return ModuleSpec(fullname, _GinoExtensionCompatNoopLoader(mod))
        elif fullname.startswith(__name__):
            raise ImportError(
                "Cannot import {} - is gino-{} a valid extension and installed?".format(
                    fullname, fullname[len(__name__) + 1 :]
                )
            )
```

(I included the piece of code as https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports says that I should include it in hidden-import,which I did)

How should I proceed with debugging the problem?